# Using User Input to Index List in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, python-3.8

I can't understand what I am doing wrong with this method. It is called from another in class method as such:

```
def equip_menu(self): # this is not the actual method, but equip_choice is used only in the following lines
    #snipped code
    equip_choice = Input("Input the number of the item you want to equip:\n")
    self.select_from_list_equip(equip_choice)
```

and this is the method throwing error:

```
def select_from_list_equip(self, equip_choice): # Trying to select item in list self.backpack
    item_to_equip = self.backpack[equip_choice]
    print("*DEBUG* Equip chosen:", item_to_equip.name)
    playeritems.equip(item_to_equip)
```

I get the error:

```
"classes.py", line 109, in select_from_list_equip
    item_to_equip = self.backpack[count]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"
```

So I tried making equip_choice an integer, even though I just try inputting digits without decimals and still get the error. I am in the opinion that I am not trying to use a string as list index, but obviously I am wrong. So I tried to force equip_choice to become an integer like this:

```
def select_from_list_equip(self, equip_choice):
    int(equip_choice)
    item_to_equip = self.backpack[equip_choice]
    print("*DEBUG* Equip chosen:", item_to_equip.name)
    playeritems.equip(item_to_equip)
```

But I still get the same identical error. Why can't I use the value of equip_choice as list index? I must be missing something very obvious and basic I am blind to?

Comment: Convert it to `int(input("Input the number..."))` also add code to handle the case where what the user types can't be parsed as an int.

Answer (score 2):

`Input()` returns a string. You will need to use `int()` to convert to an integer.

`input()` [resource](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp)